Can not import SQL .db into Azure DS
I am interested in uploading a .db file to Azure Data Studio for SQL work or exploring other tools that might be more effective. Despite my efforts to research, I haven't found a clear solution. Most resources focus on importing .sql files rather than .db files directly. I'm seeking advice on managing .db files in Azure Data Studio or recommendations for alternative tools that could better support this task. If you have any insights or suggestions on how to efficiently handle .db files in SQL environments or know of superior tools beyond Azure Data Studio, your expertise would be invaluable. Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Azure Data Studio is just an IDE, so is this ".db" file a text based file? If so, it'll have no issues opening it.


Can not import SQL .db into Azure DS

Below is another approach to import db into sql server in SSMS. A sample db file stored in local machine. Follow the below steps to import that file into the SQL Server.

Right click on Databases and select Import Data-tier Application.


Enter the path of the db file which is to be imported and click Next.


Enter the new db name to save in the server and click Next.


Verify the provided details and click Finish.


The db imports successfully into the server as shown below.




